# create angular material theme dynamically

Tags: angular, sass, material-design, angular-material2

i'm looking for the best way to implement the following :

I have two different projects - app and app-admin. I need to allow admin users to change the app theme: dark/light theme, font, primary and accent colors.

I want to only compile .scss files, create a minified custom-theme.css and include it at the bottom of my index.html. 
but i'm not sure which .scss files to compile in the server to get the new bundle css.

If you have other suggestions how to do that... 
Thanks

Comment: I am sorry, but your question seems off topic on SO, btw this guide should help you https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

Comment: yes the question is not that clear.. thanks for replying. I'm trying to understand how to set a new theme without re build the whole project, only the scss files, then include the new custom-theme.css but i'm not sure how to do that

Comment: @Shaniqwa were you able to provide a new theme without building?

Comment: yes, I will update my solution now

Answer (score 0):

Update on my solution for this:

1. added a side-panel with form to allow user to change whatever I want them to change: fonts, colors, theme, etc. (the side panel is displayed only for admin users)
2. each change triggers a function that inserts the selected values into an angular theme scss as a *string*.
3. compile the scss string with any client-side library that does that (or post to your server and to it there if you want) to get a new angular theme CSS.
4. include that theme dynamically by adding a style node to your HTML (I kept removing the previous one and adding the updated theme)
5. after the user is happy, clicks 'save changes', post the final CSS to the server and store it.
6. when loading the app, use a Resolver to fetch the theme before the page is loaded